# tf_cc_binary() makes opencv unable to load an image

Tags: c++, opencv, tensorflow, bazel

I try to load an image with opencv and work further on it with the tensorflow framework. Unfortunately I get a really weird behaviour:

The image is loaded without problems using `cc_binary(...)` in Bazel. Changing it to `tf_cc_binary(...)` doesn't stop the code from compilation or running, but opencv can't load any images any more.

```
load("//tensorflow:tensorflow.bzl", "tf_cc_binary")

#tf_cc_binary( <-- using this, no image could be loaded anymore
cc_binary(
    name = "main",
    srcs = ["main.cpp"],
    linkopts = [
        "-lopencv_core",
        "-lopencv_highgui",
        "-lopencv_imgcodecs",
        "-lopencv_imgproc",
    ],
    visibility=["//visibility:public"]
)
```

I use the standard example code from the opencv website. Again, it is working and the image is loaded using `cc_binary(`:

```
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <iostream>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

int main( int argc, char** argv )
{
    Mat image;
    image = imread("tensorflow/test/imageHolder/data/example.jpg", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);   // Read the file

    if(! image.data )                              // Check for invalid input
    {
        cout <<  "Could not open or find the image" << std::endl ;
        return -1;
    }

    namedWindow( "Display window", WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );// Create a window for display.
    imshow( "Display window", image );                   // Show our image inside it.

    waitKey(0);                                          // Wait for a keystroke in the window
    return 0;
}
```

I found this definition of `tf_cc_binary(...)`:

```
# Links in the framework shared object
# (//third_party/tensorflow:libtensorflow_framework.so) when not building
# statically. Also adds linker options (rpaths) so that the framework shared
# object can be found.
def tf_cc_binary(name,
                 srcs=[],
                 deps=[],
                 linkopts=[],
                 **kwargs):
  native.cc_binary(
      name=name,
      srcs=srcs + _binary_additional_srcs(),
      deps=deps + if_mkl(
          [
              "//third_party/mkl:intel_binary_blob",
          ],
      ),
      linkopts=linkopts + _rpath_linkopts(name),
      **kwargs)
```

I don't even understand exactly what the problem is. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

The `tf_cc_binary` is just a macro around `cc_binary` to add some tensorflow specific attributes (from the code I see it's adding [//tensorflow:libtensorflow_framework.so](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/ea94bbe9fa9f9b3d01fb057c02ef7873d76bf09c/tensorflow/tensorflow.bzl#L243) and some [rpaths](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/ea94bbe9fa9f9b3d01fb057c02ef7873d76bf09c/tensorflow/tensorflow.bzl#L222). I don't know what causes your problem right away, but I have 2 suspects:

- you depend on `libopencv_core`, but bazel doesn't know it's a dependency (here is a nice thread about this problem: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/bazel-discuss/Ndd820uaq2U)
- Ignore this if you're not running your test using `bazel run` or `bazel test`. You read `tensorflow/test/imageHolder/data/example.jpg` but again, bazel doesn't know about this file, so you should add it as a `data` dependency.

What I'd do to debug this further is to run bazel with `sandbox_debug` to see what files bazel copies to the sandbox, and with `--subcommands` to see what command line bazel generates and see what changes. You can also incrementally add/remove attributes in tf_cc_binary macro implementation to see what change triggers the problem.

Comment: What do you mean with `data` dependency?

Comment: Dependencies specified in [this](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/be/common-definitions.html#common.data) attribute.